# Node passport.js authentication without directly saving user to database

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have been googling this for almost 2 weeks and still haven't found a solution to my problem.

I have the following situation:

1. The user registers from a registration form (email, password, confirm password).
2. PassportJS validates the user (checks if the email already exists in the database)
3. The problem:

   All examples show how if the user doesn't exist in the database, one is created, saved, and in the save callback, done(null, newUser) is called. (I don't want this).

   What I really need is the user to be saved in session, then to redirect to another form where he can add Names, Country and complete the registration.
   How can I do this without losing req.user from passport? Do I need 2 local strategies? One for just validation the email does not exist and the second for actually saving the new registered user to database and creating req.user object;

Comment: The problem is when I setup the Facebook strategy
`passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID        : facebookAuth.appId,
        clientSecret    : facebookAuth.secret,
        callbackURL     : facebookAuth.callback
    },
    function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {`
I don't have access to the request object to put the facebook info in the session...

Comment: You could achieve this with custom passport configuration but before I'd liek to ask: is there any reason again saving an incomplete user in the database with a special property (ex. `incomplete: true`) indicating its state, so that login with this profile is disabled? When user completes the registration you can just update the user and mark it as complete.

Comment: That was my original idea but after discussing it with my team, we decided that we don't want uncompleted registrations in our database. There should be only 2 states: registered and not registered. `passReqToCallback : true` should do the trick.